# why is my grails integration testing of my web api failing?

Tags: integration-testing, grails-2.3

I am developing an app that appends all the values of the form to a `FormData()` object e.g. "`msgBody`" and sends it to the grails server-side where it is consumed by `jax-rs` api. I have used something like:

```
GrailsWebRequest request = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
def params = request.getParams()
if (!(params.msgBody.length() > 0)) {
    log.error("Empty message body")
}
```

The problem I am having is with the integration testing of that api where I have written:

```
def headers = ['Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZ7dAiucrA3eTbjzI', 'Accept': 'application/json']
def content='{"msgBody":"Hello World"}'
sendRequest("/api/v1/message", 'POST', headers, content.bytes)
```

I keep on getting the "`500 Internal Server Error`" and error message:

```
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method length() on null object".
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that you don't need to set the Content-Type in the headers and you also have to set all the fields of the FormData() object even if they are null. I did so but still I am getting the same NullPointerException message.